# javascript, remove common parameter from child classes

Tags: javascript

I have defined a Axios base class like this

```
   class BaseService {
    constructor(baseurl, defaultHeaders, errorCallback) {
    const options = {
      baseURL: baseurl,
      headers: defaultHeaders
    };
    this.fetcher = axios.create(options);
  }
}


class serviceA extends BaseService {}
class serviceB extends BaseService {}
```

then I am creating multiple instance like this

```
const serviceA = new ServiceA(IVA_URL,defaultHeaders,setloggedInUser);
const serviceB = new ServiceB(IVB_URL,defaultHeaders,setloggedInUser);
```

Now I want to remove defaultHeaders,setloggedInUser these two or more common parameters from every service constructor function.

Also defaultHeaders will be available at run time.

Comment: make defaultHeaders as default parameter with some initialized value,

Comment: in my case defaultHeaders will come at runtime and it will be common to all service, so how can i define default value

Comment: What is the point of `class serviceA` and `class serviceB`? Are they really empty?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use static members. set default value once and use multiple times.

```
class BaseService {
  static defaultHeaders;
  static defaultCallback;

  constructor(baseurl) {
    const options = {
      baseURL: baseurl,
      headers: BaseService.defaultHeaders
    };
    this.fetcher = axios.create(options);
  }
}

class serviceA extends BaseService {}
class serviceB extends BaseService {}
```

and then:

```
BaseService.defaultHeaders = defaultHeaders;
BaseService.defaultCallback = setloggedInUser;

const serviceA = new ServiceA(IVA_URL);
const serviceB = new ServiceB(IVB_URL);
```